# "dragend" event listener only firing on load (once) Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, events

I am sure i have structured this wrong, but the event listener for "dragend" is not firing. When I change the event to bounds_changed or center_changed then it only fires on the initial page load. Is there anything that stands out as to why it is behaving like this?

I basically just want to call my searchStores() function everytime the map is repositioned so it becomes reactive to the user.

```
    var map;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(36.2994410, -82.3409052);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        // create the new map with options
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);


        $("#btnSearch").click(function(){
            //Convert Address Into LatLng and Retrieve Address Near by
            convertAddressToLatLng($("#txtAddress").val());
        });

        //send user to print/save view on click
        $("#saveAs").click(function() {
            window.location.href = "https://54.90.210.118/test.html?address=" + $("#txtAddress").val() + '&radius=' + $("#radiusO").val();
        });

        //WHAT IS GOING ON WITH THIS GUY???
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "dragend", function() {
            alert('map dragged');

        });
    });

    $(document).one('ready', function(){

        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var pos = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };
                latlngloc = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.lat, pos.lng);
                map.setCenter(pos);
                $("#divStores").html('');
                searchStores(latlngloc);
            }, function() {
                handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            });
        } else {
            // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
            handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with jQuery, but why do you need document onReady and one('ready')? Don't they do the same things?

Comment: Can't see you doing anything wrong. Here is a jsfiddle using your code and it works just fine - https://jsfiddle.net/g1s7n3tm/

Comment: A downvote? huh. Anyway, it still isnt working on my end. I have tried different browsers etc. It seems to be with the geolocation function. When I comment it out the listener works just fine. So far I have removed the .one() ready, and have moved the Geolocation up into the main document.ready().  I am still playing around with options to get them to play nice. I cant seem to find the point at which the event listner is being overwritten or the map is being refreshed (therefore clearing the listener).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help! I found the issue was on another function that ended up clearing the map object and then recreating it. Therefore removing the listener. 
Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for pointing out that it worked on Jfiddle. I thought it was something to do with how I was calling it. 
I am really new to Javascript and having to teach myself bit by bit. Thanks for all the help! =)

Comment: I know your pain. Don't give up.